# Why GCP Pricing Calculator Interface is not showing completely?

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I'm trying to use the GCP pricing calculator but when the page is loaded I'm unable to view the entire interface to use the calculator. The only bottom part of the page is showing completely.

I've tried loading the page with and without sign-in, even loaded in incognito window but the problem is same. What I'm getting every time on loading the GCP pricing  calculator can be found in this image link:

[image: Problematic GCP Pricing Calculator Interface]

What's the solution to this problem?

Comment: I just brought it up and, of course, to me it looks fine.  What exact browser version are you using?  What locale are you using?

Comment: @Kolban, thank you for your response but I'm still stuck on the problem. My browser: Google Chrome, Version 81.0.4044.129 (Official Build) (64-bit), it's up to date. Locale: en_US;Locale code: en-US; Cookie: (not set)

Comment: I've checked and it looks as usual without any issues. Try disable any extensions or check prom another computer.

Comment: @SerhiiRohoza thank you for your response, as you said I've tried on all of my computers, Windows, Linux, MacOS and all the browsers I have Chrome, Edge, Safari but still the problem exists. Even not understanding what causes this problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not really a solution but I can not comment due to low point ;(

You can try this [link](https://cloudpricingcalculator.appspot.com/) rather than [this link](https://cloud.google.com/products/calculator)

From console message this seems to be possibly related with ISP.

I could not produce this in any browser in my pc though (ubuntu18.04, chrome81.0.4044.122 (Official Build) (64-bit), firefox75.0), except slow loading of the app while using this [link](https://cloud.google.com/products/calculator) to access.

Comment: thank you ;). Following your answer it's working now.